# MYSQL 3table join query not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to execute a simple query where three table are joined to create a single one.
I've been trying to figure out why I am not getting any results.

This is my query:

```
"SELECT b.band_naam, p.pod_omschr"
+ " FROM bands b"
+ " JOIN bandsperfestival bf ON b.band_id = bf.band_id"
+ " JOIN podia p ON bf.pod_id = p.pod_id"
```

I'm trying to do this in Java, hence the quotes.

Here's what the tables look like:

Bands

[image: Bands]

Bandsperfestival (bridge table)
[image: Bandsperfestival (bridge)]

Podia
[image: Podia]

Can someone spot my error?

Here is some more code as requested:
This is within <% and %> tags

```
        //ResultSet aanmaken voor alle groepen van op het festival
        connectie.voerQueryUit("SELECT b.band_naam, p.pod_omschr"
            + " FROM bands b"
            + " JOIN bandsperfestival bf ON b.band_id = bf.band_id"
            + " JOIN podia p ON bf.pod_id = p.pod_id", lijstParams);
        ResultSet bands = connectie.haalResultSetOp();
```

The same method with another query works perfectly like this:

```
        //ResultSet aanmaken voor het gekozen festival
        connectie.voerQueryUit("SELECT f.fest_id, f.fest_naam, f.fest_locatie, f.fest_datum, f.fest_duur, f.fest_einddatum, f.fest_url"
                + " FROM festivals f"
                + " WHERE f.fest_naam = ?", lijstParams);
        ResultSet fest = connectie.haalResultSetOp();
        fest.first();
```

And within my html I do this:

```
<ul>
    <% while (bands.next()) { %>
    <li><%= bands.getString("band_naam") %></li>
    <li>Podium: <%= bands.getString("pod_omschr") %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

The variable connectie is an instance of a class with these functions:

```
public void voerQueryUit(String query, List<String> parameters)
{
    try
    {
        if(parameters.size() > 0)
        {
            //Reden preparedStatement: geen SQL-Injectie!
            prepStatement = connectie.prepareStatement(query);

            //Lijst met parameters uitlezen om de preparedStatement op te vullen
            for(int i=1; i<=parameters.size(); i++)
            {
               prepStatement.setString(i, parameters.get(i-1));
            }
            inhoudQuery = prepStatement.executeQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            statement = connectie.createStatement();
            inhoudQuery = statement.executeQuery(query);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
}

public ResultSet haalResultSetOp()
{
    return inhoudQuery;
}
```

I know this works as it has been used multiple times.

Comment: it's should working because there is no any error .

Comment: which error you got ?

Comment: That's what I thought, it should work...
I'm not getting any errors, I'm using glassfish and phpmyadmin.
There are no errors in the log either. I'm not getting any results.

Comment: please share some code you did tried it .

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with `Query`.

I think the **error** is with `Code.`

Comment: I don't think so, when doing the same query but only selecting pod_id I am getting the results I wanted.

Comment: Where are you storing the result in `Array`, or `String`?

Comment: only the parameters a passed in an 'ArrayList'. Everything is else done with a 'ResultSet'

Comment: In that case please provide the **CODE**

Answer (score -1):

Would this work instead:

```
SELCT b.band_naam, p.pod_omschr
FROM  bands b, bandsperfestival bf, podia p
WHERE b.band_id = bf.band_id AND bf.pod_id = p.pod_id
```

Comment: I did not give you the downvote ;)
Unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can suggest a few reasons: (i) you are using the implicit rather than the explicit join syntax - the former is generally deprecated; (ii) you have misspelt `SELECT`; (iii) this query is functionally identical to the original, so is likely to exhibit the same problem as the original.

Comment: I did correct the SELCT, that's no big deal, but I did want an explicit join.